# Tornado next query string URL parameter

Tags: python, url, parameters, tornado

## Question

Since *Tornado* append a next query string parameter, which contain the URL of the resource building the redirect URL, sometimes we can redirect the user back to the referring page after login or logout applying line `self.redirect(self.get_argument("next", "/"))`

But when I use this in the following code, It didn't work.
Without login, when visiting Page */test*, it will redirect to */login?next=%2Ftest*, but the parameter *next* is always null and it will be redirect to *root page* instead of */test*.

How can I fix this problem?

## code

```
import os
import tornado.wsgi
import tornado.web
import tornado.options
import tornado.ioloop

class BaseHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get_current_user(self):
        return self.get_secure_cookie("user")

class MainHandler(BaseHandler):
    @tornado.web.authenticated
    def get(self):
        self.render('index.html', user = self.current_user)

class LoginHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        if self.get_current_user():
            self.redirect('/')
            return
        self.render('login.html')

    def post(self):
        self.set_secure_cookie("user", self.get_argument("username"))
        self.redirect(self.get_argument('next', '/'))

class LogoutHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        if not self.get_current_user():
            self.redirect('/')
            return
        self.clear_cookie("user")
        self.redirect(self.get_argument("next", "/"))

class TestHandler(BaseHandler):
    @tornado.web.authenticated
    def get(self):
        self.write("Testing!)

settings = { 
    "static_path" : os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "static"),
    "template_path" : os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "templates"),
    "login_url" : "/login",
    "cookie_secret" : "61oETzKXQAGaYdkL5gEmGeJJFuYh7EQnp2XdTP1o/Vo=",
    "gzip" : True,
    "debug" : True,
}

application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/", MainHandler),
    (r"/login", LoginHandler),
    (r"/logout", LogoutHandler),
    (r"/test", TestHandler),
], **settings)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `get` method of `LoginHandler`, use the `next` argument for the redirect

```
...

class LoginHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        if self.get_current_user():
            self.redirect(self.get_argument('next', '/')) # Change this line
            return
        self.render('login.html')

...
```

Comment: I don't understand why `get` method needs to have this. User enters the credentials, `post` method handles it and does redirection. But then why `get` method needs it?

Comment: @avi This is useful when users navigate to your login form page (say from a 'login' link on your public home page) and you wish to auto-redirect loggedin users

Comment: I still don't get it. User visits a protected page which requires login. He will be redirected to login form and next parameter includes the protected page. He enters the login and it will be handled by POST of login handler method and it will do the redirection. Where does GET of login comes into picture here?

Comment: @avi Say a user have already logged in, but somehow he navigates to the login page again. What should happen? You should not render the login form for him because he is an authenticated user! That's why.