# Fail to fetch the 'next' parameter in query-string using Tornado's self.get_argument() method?

Tags: python, http, python-2.7, redirect, tornado

As far as I have learnt, **Tornado** will append a **"next"** query string parameter, automatically, representing the source url which causes the redirection. And we can use it to redirect the user back to the page where he/she wanna visit.

Therefore, I tried to construct my `post()` method of the `LoginHandler` like this:

```
class LoginHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        pass  #some code here

    def post(self):
        [...] #some code here:verify user identity

        #if passed the verification
        self.set_secure_cookie("username", username)

        #redirect the user back to the page he wanna visit
        self.redirect(self.get_argument("next", "/"))
```

But the redirection doesn't work well. It always redirect the user back to the root url "`/`". It seems that no **"next"** argument has been found, and `get_argument()` method always return the default url "`/`".

To prove my suspect, I tried to log out the `self.request.arguments` using python's `logging` mechanism, and finally confirmed: **there's no "next" argument, really**.

**MY QUESTION IS:**

- How can I make full use of the **"next"** parameter to redirect users
  back to their wanna page?

**ADDITION:**

- I found a similar question on StackOverflow:
  [Tornado next query string URL parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20290020/tornado-next-query-string-url-parameter). It recommend to transfer such redirection to the get method of LoginHandler.

**My DOUBT IS:**

When someone press the "Login" button, the browser will send `(username, password)` pairs to the server using `post()`. The `get()` method, on the other side, will not be triggerred during the period. And therefore, how can it perform a redirection?

Comment: 1. Which version of Tornado you are using? 2. Visit the page from browser. When it got redircted to login, do you see the 'next' parameter in the URL?

Comment: Tornado v3.1.0, and when it got redirected to login, I found the URL as follows: http://localhost:8000/auth/login?next=%2Fdiz

Comment: do you have `self.redirect(self.get_argument("next", "/"))` in `get` of `LoginHandler`? that should solve your issue.

Comment: That is what I'm exactly confused, as I mentioned in my question(in [My DOUBT IS] part), when I press the login button, the data of the form will be passed to the post() method, and how could the redirection in get() method be triggerred? I would be really grateful, if you can put up an answer below, and make more explicit explanations.